# Play Framework: Package Controller & routes as jar for dependency

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have few Play Framework applications (v2.2.2) that use same routes and the Controller implements the same Action for each of them. I want to extract these common routes, views & Controller into kind of abstract application and package it as jar that other Play applications can include. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to use the abstract classes with routes because each route is linked to a static method.
But you can gather all your work within a [module](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/modules).

Comment: Yes, I am looking if there is a way to setup my own module repository.